# Как прочитать и перезаписать строку в большом файле?

Tags: java

Создал файл и читаю его с помощью `BufferedReader`. Все строки в файле начинаются с 13-ти значного числа. Если быть точнее - время в миллисекундах с 1 января 1970г. (классика) `System.currentTimeMillis()` Строки нужно отсортировать и выбрать самую старую запись. Код пишу из расчёта на чтение больших файлов.

```java
        int RAM = 1024;
        long memory=0, 
        buffer=0;
        long byteN = 0;
        String line;
        File file = new File(path);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HashSet<String>littleDataList = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    while((line=br.readLine())!= null) {
                        byteN+=line.length()+1;
                        str.append(byteN+"#").append(line+System.lineSeparator());
                        memory=byteN-buffer;
                        if (memory >= RAM) {
                            String part = str.toString();
                            String singleLine = bigSortLines(part);
                            littleDataList.add(singleLine);
                            //clear StringBuffer
                            str.delete(0, str.length());
                            buffer = byteN;
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
```

После чтения, выбранную строку нужно вернуть на место в файл, но уже с новой, обновлённой датой. И в этом есть проблема... С кода выше можно заметить, что номер байта в виде `byteN+=line.length()` я пишу в каждую строку, а после сортировки разбираю. Проблема возникает при записи в файл. А пишу я следующим образом в этом же методе ниже:

```java
            String[] terms = line.split("#");
            byteN = Long.parseLong(terms[0]);
            System.out.println("byteN after sort: "+ byteN);
            String lineBytes=line.substring(terms[0].length()+1, line.length());
            byteN=byteN-line.length();
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
            raf.seek(byteN);
            raf.writeBytes(lineBytes);
            raf.close();
        }
```

Запись работает через "ж.."утко неправильно, хотя я проверяю, что всё становится на свои позиции(банально выводя в консоль все данные), как было вычитано с файла. Почему при записи в файл получается какой-то каламбур?

Comment: У вас же текстовый файл, верно? Про байты символов перевода строки не забыли?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Забыл. Помню, что так считать байты `byteN+=line.length();` неправильно. А почему - не помню... Визуально нет никакой разницы с `raf.getFilePointer()` Однако, со временем начинают плавать ~1-2 знака, из-за чего потом не получается нормально записать в файл. Пробовал добавлять перенос каретки `\r\n` при записи, но это если и помогает, то через раз..

Comment: Символы в строках не соответствуют байтам в файле. Вам нужно читать файл в двоичном режимы, вместо строк должны быть массивы байтов.

Answer (score 1):

```java
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        //читаем строку с позиции N
        raf.seek(byteN);
        raf.readLine();
        //проверяем позицию курсора
        byteN=raf.getFilePointer();
        //позиционируем курсор на начало строки
        byteN=(byteN-1)-(lineBytes.length()+1);
        raf.seek(byteN);
        //пишем строку
        raf.writeBytes(lineBytes);
    raf.close();
```

Comment: Результаты тестов: Создал файл на 82, 7Mb; ставлю RAM = 10485760; //10Mb; Использую две сортировки: 1-я обрабатывает "пакеты" по 10Mb ("ShellSort"); 2-я ("bubbleSort") сортирует 9 строк полученные в `littleDataList` после первой сортировки: Run time - 3617ms. Win-x64; Core 2 Duo 3,30Ghz.